# Authentication in rails 5 with devise

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm working on authentication using the Devise gem, and I need to use the same database used by Moodle 2.7, so I can't modify it.

Is there any way to use valid_password?()  considering the Moodle 2.7 database structure?

My user model is:

```
create_table "mdl_user", id: :bigint, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci", comment: "One record for each person" do |t|
  t.string  "auth",  
  t.boolean "confirmed",   
  t.boolean "policyagreed",        
  t.boolean "deleted", 
  t.boolean "suspended",
  t.bigint  "mnethostid",
  t.string  "username",         
  t.string  "password",                            
  t.string  "idnumber",                            
  t.string  "firstname",        
  t.string  "lastname",       
  t.string  "email",             
  t.boolean "emailstop",             
  t.string  "icq",               
  t.string  "skype",             
  t.string  "yahoo",
  t.string  "aim",
  t.string  "msn",          
  t.string  "phone1",
  t.string  "phone2",         
  t.string  "institution",  

end
```